# Install Teamspeak Client on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, 14.10, client, teamspeak

Today I tried to setting up a Teamspeak client for my Ubuntu Server (14.10). I tried to create a music bot.
I am already at the point where i have the ts3client_runscript.sh and the other files in one directory. 
But when I try to start the client it gives me the following error message

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
./ts3client_runscript.sh: line 17: 13068 Aborted (core dumped)            
./ts3client_linux_amd64 $@
```

What does this mean and what can I do to fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install Team Speak on Ubuntu server, because Ubuntu server doesn't have a graphical interface, and the Team Speak client is only a graphical program.

> QXcbConnection: Could not connect to **display**

So, if you want to use the Team Speak client, you have to install Ubuntu desktop on your computer.